# No mapview in Pallette Android Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview

I've not seen mapview in the Palette when working with a layout in my ADT. I've searched all the categories. Where is it?

I've tried putting in the XML code directly into the layout file but I'm not seeing:

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout? Use the
>   Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix
>   the theme style references.
>
> Failed to find style 'mapViewStyle' in current theme

Am I supposed to import some extra libraries somehow?

My project is set to target Google APIs level 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps v1, which had a MapView in the Palette, has been deprecated in favor of [Google Maps v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), which does require you to import the [Google Play Services Library](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html).

The [Google Maps v2 Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html) has details on how to get started using Maps v2.